# how to debug result of if(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_DONE)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

I just can't figure.. I've seem people debugging by NSLog... isn't there a IDE integrated way to check this out? like watchlist

this code is returning false, and I just want to see what is going on there..

```
if(sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_DONE)
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not done, that's the problem. It either encountered an error or has more rows. If you want to trace it in the debugger, you need something to actually *watch*. For example:

```
int result = SQLITE_DONE;
if( (result = sqlite3_step(select stmt)) == SQLITE_DONE ) /* do stuff */
```

Now you can actually break here, or watch the `result` variable (although, given its automatic scope, watching it wouldn't be extremely useful). Also, with any debugger, the more your code is compacted onto a single line, the harder it is for the debugger to reasonably let you know what's going on. If you had broken out your code more, it'd be obvious where to stop the debugger:

```
int result = sqlite_step(selectstmt);
if( result == SQLITE_DONE ) /* do stuff */ // <- now it's easy to see what's going on in a debugger
```

Comment: @EdwinSnts There's definitely a watch, but you need something to actually watch first! The newest (as yet unreleased) version of Xcode, when using the `LLDB` debugger, also allows you to step into/out of methods and see what they returned (even when they're all on one line, like yours). So, when Xcode 4.5 is released, you'll have essentially what you want. Until then, you either need a variable to watch, or need to break up the lines of code.